# print out unique lines in Perl

Tags: perl, unique

I've been challenged with a mathematics problem. Given ten numbers (in this case, numbers from 1 to 10), how many unique combinations of six numbers are there? The short answer is 210. However, I would like to know what these combinations are.

I have put the following code together. The first while loop works fine to create a lot of sorted combinations, however, I haven't been able to print out only the unique line combinations. How can I print out these unique lines?

```
my %hash;
my @sorted_numbers;

# make all permutations with numbers from 1 to 10
my $permutor = List::Permutor->new (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
while ( my @permutation = $permutor->next() ) {
        my $string = "@permutation";
        my ($N1, $N2, $N3, $N4, $N5, $N6, $N7, $N8, $N9, $N10) = split (/ /, $string);

        # chose only the first six numbers and sort them in ascending order
        my @numbers = ($N1, $N2, $N3, $N4, $N5, $N6);
        @sorted_numbers = sort {$a <=> $b} @numbers;
}

# print out the unique number combinations from the temp file
my @unique_combinations = uniq @sorted_numbers;
foreach ( @unique_combinations ) {
    print $_, "\n";
}
```

Comment: You do not need to first turn `@permutation` into a string, and then split it again. Just use `@numbers = @permutation[0..5]`. And it seems a little strange to sort the numbers... isn't the point of this whole exercise to find the different permutations?

Comment: unique combinations actually. I just have weird ways of doing things :S  but am learning ;)

Comment: Also, using a hash is often the quickest way to find unique stuff:
my @stuff = (1,2,3,3,"somestring");
my %unique;
foreach my $foo (@stuff){ $unique{$foo} = 1; } print keys %unique;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably other CPAN modules for this, but here's one way:

```
use Math::Combinatorics qw(combine);
my @comb = combine(6, 1..10);
```

Answer (score 3):

(this smells a lot like a homework problem, so I'm only going to give you a hint)

On each iteration you need to store `@sorted_numbers` some place, e.g.:

```
while (my @permutation = $permutor->next) {
    ...
    @sorted_numbers = sort { $a <= > $b } @numbers;
    push(@combinations, ...);
}

my @unique_combinations = uniq @combinations;
foreach (@unique_combinations) {  ... }
```

So you have to figure out what to push onto the list `@combinations` so that the call to `uniq` will do what you want.

Some other pointers:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) may be written (1..10)
```

You can compute `@numbers` directly from `@permutation` with an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices):

```
my @numbers = @permutation[0..5];
```